# Can I replant the propagated branch into the same pot that it is coming from?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, planting, propagation, monstera

I replanted and propagated my *Monstera* 2 months ago, and it started to grow new leaves since then.

I am trying to reshape my awkward shaped *Monstera* to look dense and compact.

My question is, can I replant the propagated branches into the same pot?

According to the previous owner the *Monestra* is 30 years old. There are 3 main branches in the current *Monestra*.

Comment: Just for clarification: you are thinking about putting the new plant *together with the existing plant* in the pot or *reusing the pot while discarding the previous plant*?

Comment: When you say you propagated your Monstera, does that mean you now have small, separate Monstera plants growing on their own in pots or something, separate from the main plant?  Perhaps a photo or two would be useful, of both the main plant and its pot and the propagated branches.

Comment: Stephie: I am thinking to put the plant together with the existing plant in the pot

Comment: Bamboo: yes my propagated Monstera branches are now seperate in a water culture. They have grown roots and I am thinking to move them back to the main pot to make it more bushier.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between whether you can and whether you should.  Large old monstera's are always sprawling.  It's just the nature of the plant.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstera_deliciosa) for

> this plant can grow to over 30 ft (9.1 m) in many cases

If you put the cuttings with their small undeveloped root systems they will not be able to compete with the larger plant. You are better off potting them up in small pots and growing them on.  Have a collection if your place is large enough!

This could be your plant with the right light and humidity....
[image: Monstera deliciosa courtesy of http://www.terrain.net.nz/friends-of-te-henui-group/weeds/fruit-salad-plant-monstera-deliciosa.html]